# Mongo - dot notation works like $or? Can't provide multiple parameters?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I tried to update an existing document with two dot notation parameters, my query:

`{ _id: "4eda5...", comments._id: "4eda6...", comments.author: "john" }`

my update was:

`{ "comments.$.deleted": true }`

However, weirdly enough, when I passed a non-existent combination of comment id+author, it just updated the first matching comment by that author.

Any ideas why that's happening?

EDIT: C# Code sample

```
var query = Query.And(Query.EQ("_id", itemId), Query.EQ("cmts._id", commentId));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(author))
    query = Query.And(query, Query.EQ("cmts.Author", author));

var update = Update.Set("cmts.$.deleted", true);
var result = myCol.Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.None, SafeMode.True);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Did you use the official C# driver? If so, can you show the C# code you used?

Comment: added a c# code sample, I don't know how I can elaborate more - a comment with the wrong _id (but right author) gets updated.

Comment: @mnemosyn, yes, official driver

Comment: hmmm, this is just a suspicion: try to get rid of that `"_id"` field in the subdocument. In some answer I gave, that turned out to be the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want $elemMatch if you want the _id and author to be in the same comment. Really, your query doesn't make much sense including the author as the id should be as unique as you can get, no?

It is based on the first matching array element which replaces the "$" in for the update.

This is working by design. It is similar to an or since it can find a document which both has the _id and an author that match in any of the array elements.

Comment: ahh... that is a security feature (sort of, hehe). I want admins and the user who posted the comment to be able to delete it. If an admin is doing it - only the _id should be matched, if the author is doing it - both the _id and author should match. I did it like that to avoid pulling the document and checking who posted the comment --- is there a better way? This is all I could think of - the id IS unique. Thanks for the $elemMatch pointer - I'll check it out (I hope it can be built in steps, so I can still use that `if` with the username)

Answer (score 0):

The query is not working the way you are expecting it to. Basically, when using the $ positional notation you need to make sure that your query only has one clause that queries an array, otherwise it is ambiguous which of the two array comparisons the $ should refer to.

In your case, you are asking for a document where:

1. The _id is equal to some value
2. The comments array contains some document where the _id is equal to some value
3. The comments array contains some document where the author is equal to some value

Nothing in your query says that 2. and 3. need to be satisfied by the same document.

So even though you are using a non-existent combination of comment._id and comment.author, your comment array does have at least one entry where the _id is equal to your search value and some other entry (just not the same one) where the author is equal to your search value.

Since the author was the last one checked, that's what set the value of the $, and that's why that array element got updated.

Comment: >Nothing in your query says that 2. and 3. need to be satisfied by the same document.

That is the confusing part, I would have expected `Query.And()` to handle that, but I guess it's works differently with arrays